# Do I need a recursive query for this?

Tags: sql, sybase, recursive-query

I have the following (simplified) table:

| group_id | member_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 8 |

It's to manage groups and their members, while a group can also be the member of a group. What I want is to get all groups where a specific ID is a member of, either directly or via another group.

So for the example above I would want to have all groups that the member with the ID 4 is a member of and the result should be (without the brackets):

(sorry for the broken 2nd table, it always look good in the preview)

### | group_id |

| 1 (via group 2)|
| 2 (via group 3)|
|3 (directly)|
|5 (directly)|
|6 (directly|

I am honestly a bit lost right now and I am not sure if researching recursive queries is the right path or if there's an easier solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you need a recursive CTE to query a hierarchical data structure using a single query.

Comment: I guess, something similar was solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68132482/mssql-how-can-i-achieve-this-possibly-with-a-recursive-function#68132482

Comment: Have you tried asking ChatGPT?